# What's Wrong With My Load Data Method?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, filereader

This is a method I'm using to load saved game data from a file. I'm getting something called error15 at some point because of this. The only thing that came up on Google was something to do with http, but that can't be it because I'm not doing anything like that. When the object prints the strings to the console, it completes the first line of saved data but doesn't go on to read the others. I have a hunch it might have to do with my use of `in.nextLine();` (is there something else I should be using instead?) If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I will love you forever.

```
/**
 * Returns a 2-dimensional 15*15 array of saved world data from a file named by x and y coordinates
 */
public String[][] readChunkTerrain(int x, int y)
{
    String[][] data = new String[15][15]; //the array we will use to store the variables
    try {
        //initiate the scanner that will give us information about the file
        File chunk = new File( "World/" + x + "." + y + ".txt" );
        Scanner in = new Scanner(
                new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(chunk)));

        //go through the text file and save the strings for later
        for (int i=0; i<15; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<=15; j++){
                String next = in.next();
                data[i][j] = next;

                System.out.println(i + j + next); //temporary so I can see the output in console
                System.out.println();
            }
            in.nextLine();
        }

        in.close(); //close the scanner
    }
    //standard exception junk
    catch (Exception e)
    {System.err.println("Error" + e.getMessage());}

    return data; //send the array back to whoever requested it
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with the 15 you get (which you should have posted BTW, and would resulted in an immediate answer) is probably an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since you try to access `data[i][15]` in your loop, which does not exists.

```
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=15; j++){
```

Your `j` loop should be adjusted to match the `i` loop as your `data` variable is initialized as `new String[15][15]`. So convert it to the following and all will work

```
        for (int j=0; j<15; j++){
```

Note the `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Thanks so much; that worked! I actually did post the error though. It just said "error15".

Comment: Thats thanks to your poor error handling. `System.err.println("Error" + e.getMessage())` does not print out much information. At least call `e.printStackTrace()` so you know where the error occurs and what kind of error it is